# Acceleration in an elliptical binary system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, binary-stars

So I'm having a bit of a problem dealing with binary systems. I'm looking at acceleration in a stellar system and am not sure where to begin. Assuming both stars are of equal masses, they'd be equal-sized ellipses. However, they'd accelerate when they approach the barycentre, right? So the acceleration is not constant in a binary ellipse. If so, is there a way I would be able to calculate the acceleration at a certain point and a potential equation for this acceleration?

I'm assuming it's something related to polar coordinates, but I'm still in high school and this is frankly a bit beyond my head to research on my own without a clue on where to start, so I'm a bit clueless here.

Comment: You are basically studying the full Kepler problem. Unlike for the geometric shape of the trajectories there is, unfortunately, no simple expression for the time dependence of the coordinates of each star. Except in special cases (like for circular orbits) we have to solve an integral for which there is no closed form expression. I don't know if this is helpful, or not, but you are on the right way. Try to understand polar coordinates, first, and then work your way trough the solution of the Kepler problem, even if it feels hard.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration in a gravitational system is easily calculated using [Newton's Law of Gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Modern_form):

$$F = \frac{Gm_1 m_2}{r^2} \hspace{0.2in}\&\hspace{0.2in} F = ma$$

For two bodies (like you describe), it is just this simple.  If there were more bodies (a so-called ['n-body system'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem)), you can just add the forces between each pair of bodies.